# angular interval clear after cancel

Tags: angularjs

I have this bit of code to start invoke an interval:

```
// Start timer function
var startTimer = function () {

    // Apply our first image
    applyImage(element);

    console.log('about to start the timer');
    console.log(timer);

    // If our timer is not running
    if (!timer) {

        console.log('start timer');

        // Start our timer
        timer = $interval(changeImage, 10000);
    }
};
```

One thing I am doing there is checking to see if the timer is anything other than null / undefined.
But I have noticed that when I call my stop function:

```
var stopTimer = function () {

    console.log('about to stop the timer')

    // If we have started our timer
    if (timer) {

        console.log('stop timer');

        // Stop it
        $interval.cancel(timer);
    }
};
```

It does not actually clear **timer** it just sets the status to 'cancelled'.
After I call **$interval.cancel(timer)** can I set **timer** to null?
Or should I change my start function to something like this:

```
// Start timer function
var startTimer = function () {

    // Apply our first image
    applyImage(element);

    console.log('about to start the timer');
    console.log(timer);

    // If our timer is not running
    if (!timer || timer.$$state.status === 2) {

        console.log('start timer');

        // Start our timer
        timer = $interval(changeImage, 10000);
    }
};
```

Comment: It's not really gonna make much of a difference one way or another. It's developer preference as to where you want to change the code. Personally I would set `timer` to undefined after canceling it just because it makes it easier to read and understand what you're doing in the `startTimer()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely set timer to null at that point... or you can delete it. The cancel call can't delete the var from the caller's scope - JavaScript doesn't have a mechanism to do this. Marking it cancelled also gives you control over what happens next, such as if you were running half a dozen intervals and needed to keep track of their states for some reason.

Note that there is a difference between delete and setting to null. Null is a perfectly legitimate value in JavaScript so setting a var to null doesn't actually indicate that it's "no longer needed" the way some people expect. The object referenced can be freed (if this was the last reference to it) but the var itself will still exist in scope.

Comment: Ok, so I could just do $interval.cancel(timer); timer = null; yeah?

Comment: Yes, and if you do this you can simplify your if() statement that checks whether the timer is set, which I'm guessing is what you're trying to do!